# Debian: installed application via flatpak, runs from search bar, missing from cmd line

Tags: debian, software-installation, flatpak

I have installed `razerCommander` via flatpak on Debian 9.0.

If I press the "windows" key on the keyboard and search for `razerCommander`, the application appears and runs when clicked (so it functions through the OS gui.

However, it does not appear on the command line, and I am unable to find it.

Where does flatpak deposit executables, and why would it appear on the applications list, but not via the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to find out executable location, e.g. razerCommander with

```
flatpak info --show-location org.gabmus.razercommander
```

To run it from command line use

```
flatpak run org.gabmus.razercommander
```

All installed flatpak apps can be listed with

```
flatpak list --app
```